# Mouse can not move on Buildroot

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

I have my own design PCB and I use A13 Allwinner microprocessor(I use Olinuxino defconfig). I tried embedded linux with buildroot. I create desktop and I can use my keyboard. But I can not use mouse. Mouse does not move. I can see mouse information(VID,PID) at the startup(Uboot). So I think myhardware works. I analyze and research on buildroot and uboot menuconfigs. Settings seems correct. Why mouse can not move? Have you any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Enable the `evtest` tool in `menuconfig`, launch it and see if you get `EV_ABS` or `EV_REL` events.

Comment: You didn't mention which UI stack you use. You may need to set some environment variable to make it point to the correct input device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I resolve problem. It is not enough to configure buildroot only. Kernel must also be configured. I missed this part.